# How can i show an banlist from all banned users?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I want to create an command like !banlist and then i want to show a list of banned users. How can I do this in NodeJS and discord.js?

Comment: Don't you think the question lacks too much information to be a practical answerable question?

Comment: Please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [make a minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) please. Did you try anything? Do you have code to share? Do you have errors you don't understand? Stack Overflow isn't a *write this for me please* website

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`Guild.fetchBans()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild?scrollTo=fetchBans) method to retrieve a [Collection](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Collection) of banned users. Keep in mind, it returns a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise).

```js
message.guild.fetchBans()
  .then(banned => {
    let list = banned.map(user => user.tag).join('\n');

    // Make sure if the list is too long to fit in one message, you cut it off appropriately.
    if (list.length >= 1950) list = `${list.slice(0, 1948)}...`;

    message.channel.send(`**${banned.size} users are banned:**\n${list}`);
  })
  .catch(console.error);
```

Answer (score 2):

Update for Discord v13

The method `guild.fetchBan(user)` is now `guild.bans.fetch(user)` in v13.
Also method `guild.fetchBans()` is now `guild.bans.fetch()`

```js
interaction.guild.bans.fetch()
.then(bans => {
          
  let list = bans.map(user => user.user.username).join('\n');
    
  if (list.length >= 1950) list = `${list.slice(0, 1948)}`;
    
  interaction.followUp(`**${bans.size} users are banned:**\n${list}`);
})
.catch(console.error);
```